# D3 bar chart using csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am trying to make a simple bar chart following an example in the "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web".

My data in csv format looks like this: 
category,number
one,20
two,60
three,5

I am doing the following:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 100;
            var barPadding = 1;

            var rowConverter = function(d) {
    return {

        category: d.category,  
        number: parseFloat(d.number)
    };
}

            var dataset;

            d3.csv("barcharttest.csv", rowConverter).then (function(data) {

                console.log(data);
                dataset=data;
});



             //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset.number.length);
               }) 
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - (d.number * 4);
               })
               .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return d.number * 4;
               })
               .attr("fill", "teal");

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this fails to produce a bar chart. 
Error on the console: bookcode.html:41 Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function 
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you start a local server for this html file? (eg: open in localhost:3000). Otherwise, the script file cannot load the data.

Comment: You are populating dataset inside a promise but then trying to use it outside the `.then`. Put everything below the comment `//Create SVG element` inside the `.then` function. And also the localhost thing.

Comment: next time when something doesn't work, open the developers tools (usually with F12), open console tab, and share the errors you see printed there

Comment: I started a local server. I changed the code putting inside .then function, but nothing changed

Comment: Error showing on the console is "bookcode.html:41 Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function".